# Seq Diagram Drawing try catch block in UML

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have a question, how can I draw try catch block in sequence diagram in UML?
Can I draw the try as the normal case and the catch as the alternative case or no?

I'm using Visio to dram the UML sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UML sequence diagram lacks of being able to visualize exceptions. There are "workarounds" however, please refer to:

- [Break](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html#N10211)
- [Sequence Diagrams: Questions & Answers](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-questions-answers.html)
- [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471039/uml-squence-diagram-visualize-validation-of-data)

Comment: @Lisa if exceptions and alternatives are important for your model than you can use the UML activity diagram's `interrupting edge` notation together with UML sequence diagram for instance in [UML Interaction Overview Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-overview-diagrams.html) or in your customized "mix" as according to http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html "_..UML specification does not preclude mixing of different kinds of diagrams.._"

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way to model exception handling in a sequence diagram. Here is how I handle it:

[image]

The above diagram is generated with Web Sequence a free (open source) chrome extension. You can get it from here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sequence/kcpganeflmhffnlofpdmcjklmdpbbmef or from the official site: https://www.zenuml.com .
To test it out, you can simply paste the following code into the code editor of the above plugin or on the site.

```
JobTask.Run() {
  try() {
    Action.Execute() {
      InternalException.throw()
    }
  }
  InternalException.Catch() {
    Logger.Error()
    HighLevelException.throw()
  }
}
```

It demonstrates that we have a try block. Within this block, we execute Action.Execute() in which InternalException could be thrown. Then we catch it, log an error and rethrow a HighLevelException, which is a quite typical exception handling strategy.